# newbie: how to get some database columns with data on production server database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rake

Whats the best way to get a list of data from a local dev database in a production database?
I thought there was a rake task to seed data in, but is there another way?

Since Only this data should insert 1time and never updates after that, how would this
best fix in a cap deployment? Or should I just manually run the import command on the server production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just want a restore, so I would just:

You should do a database backup using your dbms tools, copy the file locally, and restore it.

Comment: rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production on the production server was the way to go